Entity Framework: How to generate a (not Id) counter that resets each year
I have an entity "JobOrder" in EF that uses "Id" as incremental identifier (on SQL Server DB), with a field "Code" that is actually calculated, once the joborder is created, in this manner:
jobOrder.Code = $"TKT-{DateTime.Now.Year}-" + jobOrder.Id.ToString().PadLeft(6, '0');
I would need to change this to satisfy these new conditions:

The new format will be "TKT-YYYY-XXXX" instead of "TKT-YYYY-XXXXXX"
YYYY is calculated as DateTime.Now.Year
XXXX needs to be based on a counter, independent from Id field, that is reset to "1" when the year changes to a new one.

For example, let suppose I have the first joborder of 2024 as "TKT-2024-0001" with Id 15975, the second joborder as "TKT-2024-0002" with Id 15976 and so on. When this year will finish I will have the last joborder as "TKT-2024-0855" with Id 18830. The first joborder of 2025 must be coded as "TKT-2025-0001" with Id 18831.
Note that the difference in numbering on the Id field does not coincide with the number of records managed, because SQL Server occasionally creates gaps in the sequence.
In practice, I need to find an algorithm that generates a sequence based on the number of records of the current year and on the last number generated. If I have generated 100 records in this year but I have delete 3 of them, the next number generated must be 101 instead of 98, to avoid duplicated codes.
I have tried a small code on SQL Server side to calculate the first code of the current year:
DECLARE @y INT;
SET @y = YEAR(GETDATE());

DECLARE @i INT;
SELECT @i = MAX(Id) FROM JobOrders WHERE Id / 10000 = @y;
SELECT @i
SET @i = @y * 10000 + 1 + COALESCE(@i % 10000, 0);

SELECT @i;

But this gives me only the first code of the year and do not calculate the current code needed. I can't figure out how to modify this code to create a function on SQL Server, or how to apply this logic to build my code on Entity Framework side.
After having checked this question: How to generate an auto-incrementing ID number that resets yearly, that gave me some ideas, I would need to "translate" the sequence idea to be applied on entity framework side. I would avoid creating objects on SQL Server side.
I hope to have explained well my goal and the conditions I must consider.
Any suggestion will be really appreciated.

That answer is correct, you don't need to translate anything, only access the sequence via EF (create a stored proc and call from EF) and coordinate the reset. Probably the simplest thing would be to schedule a job on the DB that resets the sequence on the first day of the year. You want something that is persisted and reliable between concurrent requests and a database sequence handles precisely that. The only issue will be if you an insert gets rolled back or not persisted. Fetching the next sequence will "burn" a number so your job order #s won't be guaranteed to be sequential.
